# My jsTree icon folder is not visible in Angular2

Tags: css, angularjs, jstree

I have done it in Angular. It's working properly but in Angular 4 folder icon is not visible.i have added all the css and js refrence but olny text is visible not folder and checkboxes

Here is my code:

```
$('#container').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'data' : [
            { "text" : "Root node", "children" : [
                { "text" : "Child node 1" },
                { "text" : "Child node 2" }
            ]},
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: i got the problem i included jstree css file but its not working.any suggestion how it will load properly using webpack.